# node-oracledb error when executing stored procedure NJS-012

Tags: node.js, oracle, hapi.js, node-oracledb, oracle-type

I'm running Node 8.9.4, Hapi 17.4, and Oracledb 2.2.

When attempting to call a stored procedure, I get the error "NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2".  Nothing I've been able to do seems to fix the issue.  The code that calls the procedure is:

```
async function getSavedViews(req, h, server) {
    let connection = await server.app.db.getConnection();

    let bindVars = {
        P_USER_NAME:   req.payload.user_name,
        P_CONTENT_TYPE: req.payload.content_type,
        P_PROJECT_NUMBER: req.payload.project_number,
        OP_GRID_TAB_TYP: { dir: server.app.db.BIND_OUT, type: server.app.db.ARRAY } 
    }

    let res = server.methods.response();

    try {
        res.error = false;
        res.msg = "Retrieved saved views.";
        res.data = await connection.execute(
            `BEGIN APPS.XXETA_GRID_USER_CONTEXT_PKG.EXTRACT_GRID_DETAILS(:P_USER_NAME, :P_CONTENT_TYPE, :P_PROJECT_NUMBER, :OP_GRID_TAB_TYP); END;`,
            bindVars
        );
    } catch (err) {
        server.app.logger.error(err.message);
        res.error = true;
        res.msg = err.message,
        res.data = [];
    }

    return res;
}
```

The stored procedure is described as:

[image: Oracle Screenshot]

The error I get from my logger is: 2018-08-06 15:02:20 ERROR NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

The complex type that is the bound out variable looks like this...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE XXETA_GRID_CONTEXT_REC_TYP AS OBJECT
   (
        GRID_VIEW_ID NUMBER (15),
        GRID_VIEW_NAME VARCHAR2 (240),
        USER_NAME VARCHAR2 (30),
        PROJECT_NUMBER  VARCHAR2 (5)
   )
```

Comment: Binding of user defined types is now supported in node-oracledb 4, see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2019/08/28:**

Node-oracledb added support for SQL object types and PL/SQL record types in v4 (released 2019/07/25). See this section of the doc for details:
https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#objects

Given the exact same objects as listed before, the following JavaScript can now be used to do the job with far fewer lines of code than before:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./db-config.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;

  try {  
    const sql = 
     `call xxeta_grid_user_context_pkg.extract_grid_details(
        p_user_name      => :P_USER_NAME,
        p_content_type   => :P_CONTENT_TYPE,
        p_project_number => :P_PROJECT_NUMBER,
        op_grid_tab_typ  => :OP_GRID_TAB_TYP
      )`;

    const binds = {
      P_USER_NAME: 'Jane Doe',
      P_CONTENT_TYPE: 'Some Content Type',
      P_PROJECT_NUMBER: '123',
      OP_GRID_TAB_TYP: {
        dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
        type: 'HR.XXETA_GRID_CONTEXT_TAB_TYP'
      } 
    }

    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    const result = await conn.execute(
      sql,
      binds
    );

    const gridContexts = [];

    for (let x = 0; x < result.outBinds.OP_GRID_TAB_TYP.length; x += 1) {
      gridContexts.push({
        gridViewId: result.outBinds.OP_GRID_TAB_TYP[x].GRID_VIEW_ID,
        gridViewName: result.outBinds.OP_GRID_TAB_TYP[x].GRID_VIEW_NAME,
        userName: result.outBinds.OP_GRID_TAB_TYP[x].USER_NAME,
        projectNumber: result.outBinds.OP_GRID_TAB_TYP[x].PROJECT_NUMBER
      });
    }

    console.log(gridContexts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

**Previous answer:**

Complex types are not currently supported. The out bind you have specified falls in this category. Until such types are directly supported, you'll need to add a bit of wrapper code to break the complex type into one or more simple types. I show an example of this here: 
https://jsao.io/2017/01/plsql-record-types-and-the-node-js-driver/

The goal in that post is to invoke a stored procedure which accepts an array of a custom record type. To invoke it, I first have to declare some simple array types to bind into. Then I can use those arrays to create the more complex array and invoke the procedure.

In your case, you'll need to do the reverse. In the PL/SQL block, declare a local variable of type APPS.XXETA_GRID_CONTEXT_TAB_TYP. Then, after the procedure is invoked, iterate over the array and use it to populate some simple arrays (VARCHAR2, NUMBER, or DATE) and used those as your out binds.

Update:

Provided you have the following objects:

```
create or replace type xxeta_grid_context_rec_typ as object (
  grid_view_id   number(15),
  grid_view_name varchar2(240),
  user_name      varchar2(30),
  project_number varchar2(5)
)
/

create or replace type xxeta_grid_context_tab_typ as table of xxeta_grid_context_rec_typ
/

create or replace package xxeta_grid_user_context_pkg
as

procedure extract_grid_details(
  p_user_name      in varchar2,
  p_content_type   in varchar2,
  p_project_number in varchar2,
  op_grid_tab_typ  out xxeta_grid_context_tab_typ
);

end;
/

create or replace package body xxeta_grid_user_context_pkg
as

procedure extract_grid_details(
  p_user_name      in varchar2,
  p_content_type   in varchar2,
  p_project_number in varchar2,
  op_grid_tab_typ  out xxeta_grid_context_tab_typ
)

is

  l_xxeta_grid_context_rec xxeta_grid_context_rec_typ;

begin

  op_grid_tab_typ := xxeta_grid_context_tab_typ();

  for x in 1 .. 3
  loop
    l_xxeta_grid_context_rec := xxeta_grid_context_rec_typ(
      grid_view_id   => x,
      grid_view_name => 'Some Grid View',
      user_name      => p_user_name,
      project_number => p_project_number
    );

    op_grid_tab_typ.extend();

    op_grid_tab_typ(x) := l_xxeta_grid_context_rec;
  end loop;

end;

end;
/
```

The following Node.js code can invoke the stored procedure and get the values from the complex out parameter.

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const config = require('./dbConfig.js');

async function runTest() {
  let conn;

  try {
    const userName = 'Jane Doe';
    const contentType = 'Some Content Type';
    const projectNumber = '123';

    // This is what we want to populate with records/objects that come out
    // of the procedure.
    const gridContexts = [];

    // We start by declaring some other arrays, one for each field in the
    // xxeta_grid_context_rec_typ type.
    const gridViewIds = [];
    const gridViewNames = [];
    const userNames = [];
    const projectNumbers = []; 

    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(config);

    // Then we execute the procedure with a little wrapper code to populate
    // the individual arrays.
    let result = await conn.execute(
     `declare

        -- This is a local variable that you'll use to get the out data from
        -- the procedure.
        l_xxeta_grid_context_tab xxeta_grid_context_tab_typ;

      begin

        xxeta_grid_user_context_pkg.extract_grid_details(
          p_user_name      => :user_name,
          p_content_type   => :content_type,
          p_project_number => :project_number,
          op_grid_tab_typ  => l_xxeta_grid_context_tab
        );

        -- Now that the local variable is populated, iterate over it to
        -- populate the individual out binds.
        for x in 1 .. l_xxeta_grid_context_tab.count
        loop
          :grid_view_ids(x) := l_xxeta_grid_context_tab(x).grid_view_id;
          :grid_view_names(x) := l_xxeta_grid_context_tab(x).grid_view_name;
          :user_names(x) := l_xxeta_grid_context_tab(x).user_name;
          :project_numbers(x) := l_xxeta_grid_context_tab(x).project_number;
        end loop;

      end;`,
      {
        user_name: userName,
        content_type: contentType,
        project_number: projectNumber,
        grid_view_ids: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          maxArraySize: 200
        },
        grid_view_names: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.STRING,
          maxArraySize: 200
        },
        user_names: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.STRING,
          maxArraySize: 200
        },
        project_numbers: {
          dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT,
          type: oracledb.STRING,
          maxArraySize: 200
        }
      }
    );

    // At this point you can access the individual arrays to populate the 
    // original target array with objects. This is optional, you can work
    // with the individual arrays directly as well.
    for (let x = 0; x < result.outBinds.grid_view_ids.length; x += 1) {
      gridContexts.push({
        gridViewId: result.outBinds.grid_view_ids[x],
        gridViewName: result.outBinds.grid_view_names[x],
        userName: result.outBinds.user_names[x],
        projectNumber: result.outBinds.project_numbers[x]
      });
    }

    console.log(gridContexts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

runTest();
```

I hope that helps! Direct support for complex types is on the list of enhancements, just can't say when it will land.

Comment: Am I going to have to change the stored procedure on the database?  If so, that's not going to work. I have no ability to alter the database at all.  Please, excuse me if that question sounds idiotic.  I know next to nothing about PLSQL.

Comment: No, you will not have to change the stored procedure. Please show me what APPS.XXETA_GRID_CONTEXT_TAB_TYP looks like and I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I will do so as soon as I find out.  My permissions on the database only lets me see the signature.  I can't see what that custom type looks like.  The DBA will have to tell me.

Comment: Dan, I've updated the original post with the complex type.