# Pass Object as input parameter to stored procedure with node-oracledb in node js

Tags: node.js, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes two input parameters and gives one output parameter.
Input parameters one is Oracle custom Type, second one is CHAR type
Output parameter is Number type

```
PROCEDURE SOMEPROCEDURE(
 P_REC IN RV_SEARCH_CRITERIA_REC,
 V_ITEM_BATCH_ID_FLAG IN CHAR,
 V_RV_BATCH_ID OUT NUMBER)

here RV_SEARCH_CRITERIA_REC is 
TYPE RV_SEARCH_CRITERIA_REC IS OBJECT(
   CUSTOMER_NAME   VARCHAR2(3000)
)
```

Can some one help me to access the procedure with node-oracle node module?

Comment: Please see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714223/node-oracledb-error-when-executing-stored-procedure-njs-012/51714896#51714896

Comment: Node-oracledb 4 allows binding of custom types, see https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc (id IN NUMBER, name OUT VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT last_name INTO name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = id;
END;
```

You can execute it with the following code:

```
    . . .
connection.execute(
  "BEGIN myproc(:id, :name); END;",
  {  // bind variables
    id:   159,
    name: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.STRING, maxSize: 40 },
  },
  function (err, result) {
    if (err) { console.error(err.message); return; }
    console.log(result.outBinds);
  });
```

Try to execute yours in the same way by replacing the procedure name, args and binding.

Check out the docs here: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html

Comment: For reference, documentation for the current production version of node-oracledb is at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html  The github copy of these docs may talk about upcoming features that are only available if you compile node-oracledb yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @ChristopherJones! I just updated my answer with the correct link

Comment: I am getting error *err.message ORA-24338: statement handle not execute* can any one help me with this