# How fix ORA-06550 call

Tags: node.js, typescript, oracle

i have problem to call a oracle method into my nodejs api i don't know how i fixing it, need help. Bellow is my code and error.

**CONTROLLER**

```
async lov_local_estoque(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
      let { operator } = super.openToken(req);
      let { p_fil_filial, p_out } = req.body;
      let info = await this.rep.lov_local_estoque(p_fil_filial, p_out, req.query.userPool);
      res.json(info);
    } catch (error) {
      catchErr(res, error);
    }
  }
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
public async lov_local_estoque(p_fil_filial: string, p_out:string, userPool: any): Promise<any> {
    let conn = await connection(userPool);
    try {
      let ret = await conn.execute(
        `DECLARE
          c_out SYS_REFCURSOR;
         BEGIN
         brio.pck_erp_coletor_api.lov_local_estoque(
          p_fil_filial => :p_fil_filial,
          p_out => :p_out);
         END;`,
        {p_fil_filial, p_out},
        { autoCommit: true }
      );
      return ret.implicitResults[0];
    } catch (e) {
      return { info: e.message };
    } finally {
      if (conn) conn.close();
    }
  }
```

**ROUTE**

```
{
    method: "get",
    route: `${Constantes.route.auth}/lov-local-estoque`,
    controller: LovController,
    action: "lov_local_estoque",
},
```

**ERROR => "info": "ORA-06550: line 4, column 10:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'LOV_LOCAL_ESTOQUE'\nORA-06550: line 4, column 10:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52167622/pass-object-as-input-parameter-to-stored-procedure-with-node-oracledb-in-node-js

Comment: You need to specify your out-bind variable with `oracledb.BIND_OUT`

Comment: like this {
          p_fil_filial,
          p_out: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT },
        }