# How to return generated ID in an oracle procedure with node-oracledb library

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I wrote a procedure and I need to return the last generated ID when doing an insert in the database using the node-oracledb library.

I'm using DBMS_OUTPUT to return the value of a variable declared in the procedure, I can return the value output in SQL Developer, but I can't return it in the node-oracledb library.

Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE       TESTE.CREATE_PATIENT(
    p_DT_NASCIMENTO IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.DT_NASCIMENTO%TYPE,
    p_IE_SEXO IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.IE_SEXO%TYPE,
    p_NR_CPF IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_CPF%TYPE,
    p_NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG%TYPE,
    p_NR_PASSAPORTE IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_PASSAPORTE%TYPE,
    p_NM_PESSOA_FISICA IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NM_PESSOA_FISICA%TYPE,
    p_CD_ACOMPANHANTE IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA_ACOMPANHANTE.CD_ACOMPANHANTE%TYPE,
    p_NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR IN TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR%TYPE
  )
IS
    p_CD_PESSOA_FISICA NUMBER;
    BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA (DT_NASCIMENTO,IE_SEXO,NM_PESSOA_FISICA,NR_CPF,NR_PASSAPORTE,NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG,NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR) VALUES(p_DT_NASCIMENTO,p_IE_SEXO,p_NM_PESSOA_FISICA,p_NR_CPF,p_NR_PASSAPORTE,p_NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG,p_NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR) RETURNING CD_PESSOA_FISICA INTO p_CD_PESSOA_FISICA;
    INSERT INTO TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA_ACOMPANHANTE (CD_PESSOA_FISICA, CD_ACOMPANHANTE) VALUES(p_CD_PESSOA_FISICA, p_CD_ACOMPANHANTE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_CD_PESSOA_FISICA);
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Call the procedure:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN CREATE_PATIENT(TO_DATE('1981-12-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'F', '25845685236', '12345645', '65432145', 'Marina Santos', '3', '+5511999999999'); END;
```

See the return:
[Return In SQL Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03tSA.png)

I need to return this value with node-oracledb, has anyone experienced this and could help me out?

Comment: If you really must use `DBMS_OUTPUT` then a method is documented [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/using-dbms_output-with-nodejs-and-node-oracledb) however you should not do that and should refactor your procedure to use an `OUT` parameter instead.

Comment: I agree about using an OUT bind.  To add a more likely to be updated reference about DBMS_OUTPUT, the node-oracledb doc on that is at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#dbmsoutput

Comment: MTO and Christopher Thank you very much! I will apply the changes and test.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `DBMS_OUTPUT`; use an `OUT` parameter:

```sql
create PROCEDURE TESTE.CREATE_PATIENT(
    p_DT_NASCIMENTO        IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.DT_NASCIMENTO%TYPE,
    p_IE_SEXO              IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.IE_SEXO%TYPE,
    p_NR_CPF               IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_CPF%TYPE,
    p_NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG%TYPE,
    p_NR_PASSAPORTE        IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_PASSAPORTE%TYPE,
    p_NM_PESSOA_FISICA     IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NM_PESSOA_FISICA%TYPE,
    p_CD_ACOMPANHANTE      IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA_ACOMPANHANTE.CD_ACOMPANHANTE%TYPE,
    p_NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR  IN  TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR%TYPE,
    o_CD_PESSOA_FISICA     OUT TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.CD_PESSOA_FISICA%TYPE
  )
IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA (
    DT_NASCIMENTO,
    IE_SEXO,
    NM_PESSOA_FISICA,
    NR_CPF,
    NR_PASSAPORTE,
    NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG,
    NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR
  ) VALUES(
    p_DT_NASCIMENTO,
    p_IE_SEXO,
    p_NM_PESSOA_FISICA,
    p_NR_CPF,
    p_NR_PASSAPORTE,
    p_NR_REG_GERAL_ESTRANG,
    p_NR_TELEFONE_CELULAR
  )
  RETURNING CD_PESSOA_FISICA INTO o_CD_PESSOA_FISICA;
  
  INSERT INTO TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA_ACOMPANHANTE (
    CD_PESSOA_FISICA,
    CD_ACOMPANHANTE
  ) VALUES(
    o_CD_PESSOA_FISICA,
    p_CD_ACOMPANHANTE
  );
END;
/
```

*Note: Using `COMMIT` in the procedure means that you cannot chain multiple procedures and/or DML statements together in a single transaction and then use `ROLLBACK` on them all if a later one fails. You should remove the `COMMIT` and call it outside the procedure when the transaction is complete.*

Then if you want to call the procedure and output the value in SQL Developer then you can use `DBMS_OUTPUT` in the block you call the procedure from:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  v_CD_PESSOA_FISICA TESTE.PESSOA_FISICA.CD_PESSOA_FISICA%TYPE;
BEGIN
  CREATE_PATIENT(
    TO_DATE('1981-12-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
    'F',
    '25845685236',
    '12345645',
    '65432145',
    'Marina Santos',
    '3',
    '+5511999999999',
    v_CD_PESSOA_FISICA
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_CD_PESSOA_FISICA);
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

You can call the same procedure in [Node and read the out parameter into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173423/1509264).

Comment: In case it helps, the 'official' doc on calling PL/SQL and binding in node-oracledb is at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#plsqlexecution

Comment: Thank you very much! I will apply the changes and test. :D